# Is it okay to chmod 770 root directory "/"?

Tags: directory, root, chmod

Output of `ls`:

```
$ ls -lh /
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root 4.0K Dec  9 18:56 boot
drwxr-xr-x  17 root   root 4.2K Dec 10 13:57 dev
drwxr-xr-x  92 root   root 4.0K Dec 10 13:57 etc
drwxrwxrwx   9 lyndon root 4.0K Dec  9 19:00 home
drwx------   3 lyndon root 4.0K Dec  6 20:05 homebackup
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   33 Dec  8 06:35 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   33 Dec  7 17:01 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 root   root 4.0K Dec  7 17:02 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Dec  7 17:06 lib64
drwx------   2 root   root  16K Dec  7 17:00 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root 4.0K Dec  7 17:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Apr 10  2014 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root 4.0K Jul 22 18:48 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 113 root   root    0 Dec 10 13:57 proc
drwx------   5 root   root 4.0K Dec  9 18:48 root
drwxr-xr-x  20 root   root  680 Dec 10 17:06 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root  12K Dec  9 18:56 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root 4.0K Dec  9 18:57 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root   root    0 Dec 10 13:57 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root   root 4.0K Dec 10 16:17 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  10 root   root 4.0K Dec  7 17:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   root 4.0K Dec  7 17:02 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   30 Dec  8 06:35 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root   30 Dec  7 17:01 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
```

What would happen if I `chmod` every subdirectory of `/` to `770`?
Would there be any errors caused by doing so?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not okay. Of course there will be errors. You will render your filesystem inaccessible to you. And will probably have to boot to a live environment to fix it.